# Evaluating convolution of two continuous functions using fftconvolve

Tags: python, scipy, julia, fft, convolution

I am trying to evaluate the convolution of two continuous functions using `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`. The scenario of the code is as following:

I am trying to approximate the following double integral:

[image]

, i.e. in a region C_1(x',y'), representing a circle of radius 1 centered at (x', y'). This can be approximated by the following integral:

[image]

where the function K is chosen as a continuous integrable function, say, `exp(-x^2-y^2)`, the shape of which is approximately that of a circle of radius 1. If I take a function K'(x,y)=K(-x,-y), then the integral is exactly a convolution of the two functions:

[image]

So I try to discretize these two functions into arrays and then carry out convolution.

The following code will be written in Julia and the `fftconvolve` function will be imported using `PyCall.jl`.

```
using PyCall
using Interpolations

r = 1
xc = -10:0.05:10
yc = -10:0.05:10

K(x, y) = exp(-(x^2+y^2)/r^2)
rho(x, y) = x^2+y^3    # Try some arbitrary function

ss = pyimport("scipy.signal")  # Import scipy.signal module from Python
a = [rho(x,y) for x in xc, y in yc]
b = [K(-x,-y) for x in xc, y in yc]
c = ss.fftconvolve(a,b,mode="same")  # zero-paddings beyond boundary, unimportant since rho is near zero beyond the boundary anyway
c_unscaled = interpolate(c', BSpline(Cubic(Line(OnCell())))) 
# Adjoint because the array comprehension switched x and y, then interpolate the array
c_scaled = Interpolations.scale(c_unscaled, xc, yc) # Scale the interpolated function w.r.t. xc, yc
print(c_scaled(0.0,0.0)) # The result of the integral for (x', y') = (0, 0)
```

The result is `628.3185307178969`, while the result from numerical integration is `0.785398`. What is the problem here?

Comment: You might want to normalize `K` so its integral is 1. And then you need to divide by `dx * dy`, which is not 1 in your code.

Comment: Where I said divide I meant multiply, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to use scipy.signal.convolve which will convolve two N-dimensional arrays, but not by using Fast Fourier Transform.
It uses a direct method to calculate a convolution. Here, I mean that the convolution is determined directly from sums.

So you could maybe try to replace the line where you calculate c with this one:

```
c = ss.convolve(a,b,mode="same", method='direct')
```

Comment: But I don't see why using FFT should be any different for getting an accurate result? And FFT should have a better performance for large array, as I heard? As I run `ss.convolve`, it seems that it runs very slowly, that maybe even using a numerical integration package might be even a better alternative. I am thinking whether the problem lies in my choices of `xc` and `yc`. As the interval is smaller, the result seems to be larger. I am thinking whether I should, say, multiply the result by 0.02, if I choose `xc` and `yc` be `-10:0.05:10`.

Comment: It seems to me that the obtained result matches the result from numerical integral if I multiply the convolution by `0.02 ** 2` and choose a narrower domain (`rho(x, y) = x^2+y^3` that I chose diverges when x and y grow larger, so `rho(x,y)` contributes to the convolution even when `x` and `y` are far away from the center)

Comment: However as I tried some other `K` and `rho`, say `g(x, y) = sin(x)*cos(2*y)` and `K(x,y) = x*y*exp(-x^2-y^2)*(1-exp(-10*y))^(-1)` (the logistic sigmoid function is to emulate a step function), it doesn't work well anymore. So I would like to know whether my use of `fftconvolve` in the case is conceptually wrong.